# Grails Tomcat Plugin - DeployTask cannot be found Error

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

I upgraded my project from using the Tomcat 7.0.54 plugin to 8.0.15, unfortunately now whenever I try to use the plugin to deploy or undeploy from a server (ie: grails tomcat deploy) I get the following error:

```
Error executing script Tomcat: taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Unfortunately, Googling this error doesn't seem to yield any information related to Grails or the Grails Tomcat plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this problem by adding the following to my BuildConfig:

```
        build 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:8.0.15'
```

That fixed the missing class problem, but it uncovered another problem with the `Tomcat.groovy` script (you'll find it under target/work/plugins}.

It's trying to pass a variable called `warName` in the deploy task, but that variable doesn't exist.  I haven't found where that is supposed to be declared yet, so I've temporarily hard-coded it to my war file's path and name.

I'm using GGTS and I had to restart GGTS to pick up the change to this file

**Edit**

Replaced the hard-coded war file name with `warCreator.warName` and it started using the name from BuildConfig